# Routing error No route matches id nil (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting the following error on a page that contains a link to credit/edit an object:

**Routing Error
No route matches {:controller=>"connections", :action=>"edit", :id=>nil}**

My app has user profile pages (#show action in users_controller.rb) with a link to create or edit an existing "connection" (a relationship between users like Facebook or LinkedIn). If the connection does not exist, the link will send the user to create a new connection. If the connection already exists, the link will send the user to edit the existing connection. My create functionality works fine. However, once the connection has been created, visiting the user page throws the routing error. It clearly does not like my link_to for the edit action.

Here is the link_to on the user page:

```
<% unless current_user == @user %>
<% if @contact.present? %>

<%= @user.first_name %> is your <%= @connection.description %> &nbsp;(<%= link_to "edit contact", { :controller => 'connections', :action => 'edit', :id => @connection.id} %> )

<% else %>

How do you know <%= @user.first_name %>? (<%= link_to "edit contact", { :controller => 'connections', :action => 'create', :user_id => @user.id }, :method => 'post' %> )

<% end %>
```

The error also specifically states that :id is set to nil (null). The problem must be here. How can I my app to refer to the correct connection? My instance variable should have done the trick.

Here's the connection controller:

```
class ConnectionsController < ApplicationController

def index
end

 def update
  @connection = current_user.connections.find(params[:id])
    if @connection.update_attributes(params[:connection])
      flash[:notice] = "Contact relationship updated"
      render 'activities'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @connection = current_user.connections.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    #@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @connection = current_user.connections.build(params[:connection])
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    if @connection.save
      flash[:success] = "Contact relationship saved!"
    else
      render @user
    end
  end
end
```

And here's the User controller show action (where the link_to exists):

```
 def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @connection = current_user.connections.build(:otheruser_id => @user)
    @contact = current_user.connections.where(user_id: current_user, otheruser_id: @user)
  end
```

routes.rb:

```
authenticated :user do
    root :to => 'activities#index'
  end
  root :to => "home#index"
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers, :posts, :comments, :activities, :works, :contributions, :connections
    end
  end
  resources :works do
    resources :comments
  end
  resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :posts
  resources :activities
  resources :reposts
  resources :comments do
    member do
      put :toggle_is_contribution
    end
    end
  resources :explore
  resources :connections
```

Any ideas on how to fix the link_to? Thanks!

EDIT 1: relevant rake routes:

```
 connections GET    /connections(.:format)                         connections#index
                               POST   /connections(.:format)                         connections#create
                new_connection GET    /connections/new(.:format)                     connections#new
               edit_connection GET    /connections/:id/edit(.:format)                connections#edit
                    connection GET    /connections/:id(.:format)                     connections#show
                               PUT    /connections/:id(.:format)                     connections#update
                               DELETE /connections/:id(.:format)                     connections#destroy
```

Comment: Have you tried `rake routes` in console to verify the route exists?

Comment: Hello and thanks for the reply. I just posted the rake routes above. It looks like it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in:

```
@connection = current_user.connections.build(:otheruser_id => @user)
```

That instantiates a connection object and assigns it to @connection. This object hasn't been saved, therefore it doesn't have an id. Conceptually it's wrong too, how can you edit something that doesn't exist yet? If you want to send the user to create a new connection, Connections#new is what you're after.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the reply. The create actions works good right now. I can create a connection using the current create action (sent there with the link_to above). However, when I try to send the user to edit an object that already exists (I can confirm by looking at it in the database), I get the routing error

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe I didn't explain well. Your edit view is right, what's not right is your users#show view, where @connection is an instance of Connection that hasn't been saved to the database yet (you just instantiated with `connections.build`). Therefore the link_to helper raises an error because @connection.id is nil

Comment: Oh ok, that makes sense. What should I change it to? I changed it to @connection = current_user.connections.find(params[:connection]) but I get an error when I visit a user page: Couldn't find Connection without an ID. I can't use :id because that's used to show the user.

Comment: If I understand your users#show action, @connection is the new Connection instance, while @contact is the existing one. Makes me think that the id you want in your link `if @contact.present?` is @contact.id.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm getting closer. Changing :id to @contact.id in the form fixed the routing error but now I get NoMethodError in Users#show
; undefined method `id' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007f887c4ea190>. Any other ideas?

Comment: I changed it to @contact.connection_id and it will load the page without an error. However, the edit URL is localhost:3000/connections/70111985738060/edit?user_id=2 and I get a postgresql error of PG::Error: ERROR:  value "70111985738060" is out of range for type integer
: SELECT  "connections".* FROM "connections"  WHERE "connections"."user_id" = 1 AND "connections"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1. How can I change the 70111985738060 to simply be 1 (the connection_id)?

Comment: `@contact = current_user.connections.where` is actually a Relation instance, that is effectively (simplifying) an array of connections, so what you want is `@contact.first`.

Comment: THANK YOU! The .first worked! I seriously can't thank you enough for the answer as well as the thorough explanations. If there's anything I can do just ask (fiverr gig, paypal, testimonial, etc)